# Removing partitions from the cube in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, olap, cube, ssms

How can I remove several partitions at once from the Cube using SQL Server Management Studio?
I remember there was a Partitions manager which allowed to select several partitions, but cannot find how to open it.

Answer (score 0):

To view the Partitions Manager dialog box, in SQL Server Data Tools, click the Table menu, and then click Partitions.

To delete a partition:

1. In Partition Manager, in the Table listbox, verify or select the table that contains the partition you want to delete.
2. In the Partitions list, select the partition you want to delete and then click Delete.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230810.aspx

Hope this helps